# Logcat in eclipse keeps auto clearing

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

until recently my logcat has been fine but all of the sudden whenever i try to view it in eclipse it just keeps clearing itself whenever anything is displayed making it impossible to read. viewing it in the adb works but I never bother with that since it is just such a pain to read and find anything you are looking for.

is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will show one line before erasing it to show the next one? Just click the verbose button again.

Answer (score 35):

The Logcat messages were simple getting cleared because the buffer had run out of space (receiving too many new messages), which is a simple setting change in Eclipse.

To fix, go to Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat

and increase the limit for "Maximum number of LogCat messages to buffer". Set it to 0 for unlimited size, or a really big number. But keep in mind, anything below 10000 fills up real fast.

Been answered already:
[Eclipse Android - Logcat Clearing too Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442892/eclipse-android-logcat-clearing-too-fast)

Comment: awesome! thanks. my app is crashing randomly and I wanted to debug it. Logcat was clearing and I was not able to. But, now I can :)

Comment: Worth to note that (at least in my case) LogCat needs to be restarted (closed and reopened) before this kicks into effect

Answer (score 5):

There's a workaround for this bug. Click active mode button (usually verbose), choose another device from device list and choose previous device again. It will restore all logcat messages.

Answer (score 0):

LogCat is really annoying for this. In Ubuntu, I found the following works really well:

Open a terminal and type `adb logcat | grep MYINFO`

This will only show adb messages filtered by the `MYINFO` string.

So, you can code something like:

```
Log.v("MYINFO", "x" + x_value + ", etc...");
```

This is such a relief to use. A life saver! See [this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_debugging_with_logcat) for more info.

You may find sometimes the logcat buffer repeats previous logs on starting again. To overcome this, type

```
adb logcat -c
```