# Eclipse Android - Logcat Clearing too Fast

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I have been using Eclipse for Android (most up to date version), for a while with no problems with the Logcat. For an unknown reason, Logcat is no longer retaining the debug messages. Logcat is getting cleared in about 5 seconds . Is there any way to prevent the auto-clearing of Logcat messages? Otherwise I am unable to read the messages.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Change your LogCat buffer length:

Window / Preferences / Android / LogCat / Maximum number of LogCat messages in buffer **_**

Set it to 0 for unlimited size (thanks to the commenter below)

Comment: Just thought I'd add, by setting to 0, on Mac Eclipse it doesn't help. the size is still cut after small amount. I had to set mine to a large number such as 500000

Comment: Hmm... using Eclipse Kepler on Mac, it goes unlimited (or at least very high) when set to 0.

Comment: Where can I find those settings on Android Studio?

Comment: Eclipse Mars on Mac looks like it limits to 5000 if the buffer size is set to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Its happens when there is too many logcat rows. It automatically delete all after reaching maximum number defined in preferences (5000 rows by default in Eclipse), both filtered and not filtered rows.

Fortunetly, you can change maximum number in:

Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat > Maximum number of LogCat messages in buffer

I have the same problem, but only with Sony Xperia C and Android 4.2.2. Every phone have different level of logging.

Answer (score -3):

You can use **breakpoints** where you print the messages and **debug them by F6/F8** keys after that. So you can see **all the messages by step**.