# Logcat logs keeps on flushing

Tags: android, logcat

I am interested in viewing logs that my app prints as warning '[Log.w(TAG,message)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#w%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)'. The logs appear in a filtered logcat windows based on the TAG. The problem is that keeps on flushing very soon and I am not able to check older logs.

I tried

- Using eclipse preferences: [Eclipse Android - Logcat Clearing too Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442892/eclipse-android-logcat-clearing-too-fast). [image]

  -
- Using adb -

  Using adb to fetch log history based on [Saving Logcat to a text file in Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565685/saving-logcat-to-a-text-file-in-android-device) but it did not show the logs which I are coming from the app using Log.w().

Can Anyone suggest a good approach?