# Configuring internal logs

Tags: android, logging

I want to configure my log settings on Android, so when I perform an

```
adb logcat -d
```

It contains max 4 log rotations, each at 1MB each.

To do this, I tried:

```
adb logcat -n 10 -r 1000
```

But it complains I need to specify -f for filename. I think this is the wrong direction, as I want to configure the internal logging while its unplugged, so when I am ready to dump the logs, I plug it in, and can dump it then.

Answer (score 0):

I see that [Eclipse Android - Logcat Clearing too Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442892/eclipse-android-logcat-clearing-too-fast) answers the question via eclipse, but what is it really sending to the device that I can run manually w/o eclipse from the commandline?