# Why does logcat auto clear

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

Has anyone encountered the issue where logcat keeps clearing itself even when there are very few messages in it?

I set the buffer size to 0 whch means unlimited.

I have checked questions like [Eclipse Android - Logcat Clearing too Fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442892/eclipse-android-logcat-clearing-too-fast) 
but still can't fix the issue.

How to fix?

Comment: Is it since you started programming with eclipse or has it occured after an update/change of settings ? Because my logcat doesn't clear itself.. Maybe i don't get you question right. If not we can compare the settings if it helps you?

Comment: add sreen shot of your Window / Preferences / Android / LogCat..

Comment: I faced the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: Get used to eclipse. Any idea how to fix the problem.