# Logcat in Eclipse keeps clearing on physical device

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logcat in eclipse keeps auto clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794796/logcat-in-eclipse-keeps-auto-clearing)

Sounds like something very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794796/logcat-in-eclipse-keeps-auto-clearing), but the answers there are not working

When I run my project on my device from eclipse, logcat shows my filtered output fine, for about a second, but then clears completely. I've tried clicking on the verbose button, changing it to debug, and selecting the device in the device chooser, none of these help.

It works as expected on a virtual device, but I'd like to start testing on a physical device.

I'm running Eclipse Juno, on Windows 8 x64. The device is an HTC Thunderbolt running android 2.3.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out the logcat on the device is picking up a bunch of entries from other software, overrunning the  log buffer which is set to 80000 characters by default. Unchecking the 'limit console buffer' option in Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Console fixes the problem. Of course the real problem is that the system is writing so much to logcat!

The virtual device is a skeleton device, with no other apps installed, so it doesn't have this problem.

Sorry to answer my own question, but I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Having the same problem on one device. Setting the buffer in eclipse to unlimited did nothing for me. Was able to see 99% of the device logging was related to bluetooth. Disabling bluetooth on the device cleared my problem but did not answer why the bluetooth service was going haywire.